# Error in Django Admin Site during template rendering- '__str__ returned non-string (type bytes)'

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, python-3.6

I would like to access a model in the admin panel of my Django app- http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/scraper/ad_history/

When i click the model link to view its entries, i get the following error:

```
TypeError at /admin/scraper/ad_history/
__str__ returned non-string (type bytes)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/scraper/ad_history/
Django Version: 2.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__str__ returned non-string (type bytes)
Exception Location: C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py in items_for_result, line 251
Python Executable:  C:\Python36-32\Anaconda\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\MyApp\\MyApp',
 'C:\\Python36-32\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python36-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Python36-32',
 'C:\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Tue, 21 Aug 2018 14:05:36 +0000

__str__ returned non-string (type bytes)
```

Ad History model:

```
class Ad_History(models.Model):
    ad = models.ForeignKey(Ad, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_found = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    keyword = models.ForeignKey(Keyword, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    kw_scrape_count = models.IntegerField()
    page_found = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)
    sequence = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ad.description
```

Admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Domain, Ad, Phone, Email, Hour, Address, Ad_History 

from scraper.forms import AdHistoryAdmin, AdAdmin, DomainAdmin

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Domain, DomainAdmin)
admin.site.register(Phone)
admin.site.register(Email)
admin.site.register(Address)
admin.site.register(Hour)
admin.site.register(Ad, AdAdmin)
admin.site.register(Ad_History, AdHistoryAdmin)
```

AdHistoryAdmin:

```
class AdHistoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('ad', 'date_found', 'kw_scrape_count', 'keyword', 'sequence')
```

I tried to change the **str** function in the model to return a dummy string (to ensure there were no bytes being returned) and this still generated the error.

Any ideas how i can get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Please show the `ad_history` model and model admin class.

Comment: Just updated with admin.py , is that what you mean? the missing 'self' reference was unintended, happened when i reverted the code from the test string.

Comment: Please show the `AdHistoryAdmin` model admin class.

Comment: The `list_display` references several different models (e.g. `ad`, `keyword`), so the problem could be with the `__str__` method for one of them.

Comment: @Alasdair, thanks this solved it for me. The problem was i upgraded my python version from 2-3 on the project and some of the __str__ functions of my models were using the str.encode('utf-8', errors='replace'). I removed that and now they all work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to input into a string but with non string values this can be done:

```
def __str__(self):
   return 'Value1={0}, Value2={1}'.format(self.value1, self.value2)
```

Comment: Im getting the same error even when i return a hardcoded string i.e. return "a string"